# grails ajax call needs to reload jquery code in each template

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.4 and AJAX request using formremote, remotelink, submittoremote etc.

when i make ajax call and rendering template i need to write related jquery again.

Like

```
$('.customdatepicker').datepicker({
                    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                    autoclose:true,todayHighlight: true
                });
```

Instred of repeating code in all template, 
I need something so that i just need to write jquery code only once.

If i defined it in layout then it is only available to all non ajax call.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain more about this - "_then it is only available to all non ajax call_"? What stops you from adding the JS file to the templates?

Comment: Hi Mikelis, I have made single js , if i include js file in template then all other code is also gets loaded.

Comment: Divide it into two files - one with the code that should be applied just to those specific templates..

Comment: Thanks.. finally i have created separate js file and loaded that file in template file where it is needed.

Comment: Damn, it took you a long time. :D But good job! It's always hard at the beggining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should consider the following:**

---

When you load content with ajax, the elements created with it do not
   automatically have all the bindings and events that all the other
   elements created at page load have. If you need your elements to have
   a certain behaviour after the ajax, then you should create functions
   that you can call in the `onSuccess` of your form remote tag.

---

You could use normal forms and use jquery's `on` function as

```
$('#my-element-in-page-when-loaded').on('click', 'my-ajax-element', function(){ /*jquery ajax functions load, get, post, ajax*/})
```

instead of

```
$('my-ajax-element').click();
```

since the latter will only work if my-ajax-element exists when the page is initially loaded.

---

if the problem is that your javascript is loaded in an incorrect order then you should code like the following to your template

```
<content tag="javascript">
    //your js
</content>
```

and the following code to your layout, after the place where you declare your resources or asset javascripts.

```
//your layout assets
<g:pageProperty name="page.javascript"/>
```

In this manner you will be able to declare a file with all your commonly used functions in a file, and then all your view specific js in the

```
<content tag="javascript">
    //your view specific code.
</content>
```